# Formatting object queries with .map FCC

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know I'm close with .map, but the format I'm using via template literals isn't passing so I think I'm using the wrong method. What am I missing here? Thanks.

**Suite question I'm not passing:**

```
"rating should equal [{"title":"Inception","rating":"8.8"},
{"title":"Interstellar","rating":"8.6"},{"title":"The Dark
Knight","rating":"9.0"},{"title":"Batman Begins","rating":"8.3"},
{"title":"Avatar","rating":"7.9"}]"
```

**My console.log(rating):**

```
[ '{"title":"Inception","rating":"8.8"}','{"title":"Interstellar","rating":"8.6"}','{"title":"The Dark Knight","rating":"9.0"}','{"title":"Batman Begins","rating":"8.3"}','{"title":"Avatar","rating":"7.9"}' ]
```

**My attempt:**

```
 var rating = [];
watchList.map((val, i, arr) => {
  rating.push(`{"title":"${val.Title}","rating":"${val.imdbRating}"}`);
});
```

**Demo test object:**

```
{
    "Title": "Avatar",
    "Year": "2009",
    "Rated": "PG-13",
    "Awards": "Won 3 Oscars. Another 80 wins & 121 nominations.",
    "imdbRating": "7.9",
    "Response": "True"
  }
```

Comment: *"Suite question I'm not passing:"* ...What do you mean?  It's wrapped in double quotes ***and*** it has nested double quotes. That makes it a group of individual strings it's not even a collection or an array-like object..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to be expecting an array of *objects*:

> "rating should equal [{"title":"Inception","rating":"8.8"}, ...

But what you have is a array of *strings*:

> [ '{"title":"Inception","rating":"8.8"}',

Try `map`ping to an array of objects instead (and use `map` properly, rather than as a `forEach` as you're currently doing - to `map`, *return* from the map function the item you want in the new array):

```
var rating = watchList.map(val => ({
  title: val.Title,
  rating: val.imdbRating
}));
```

Or, even more concisely with argument destructuring:

```
var rating = watchList.map(({ Title: title, imdbRating: rating }) => ({ title, rating }));
```

Comment: SO helpful, thank you. I understand better now, which is good because .map has tripped me up before.